# what are the small black things that fall from top ceiling of my grill?

Tags: grill

I have quite an old cooker, and when I put foil paper in I notice little black things fall onto the foil from the top of the grill (I think broiling in US) compartment. Even when I don't cook if I put something in and hit the ceiling/gas heating element I can see these little black things fall.

I'm concerned it might go onto food and I'll eat them without knowing.  Do you know what these are likely to be? Is it a hazard, or maybe time to get a new grill?

Comment: Pictures might help. Have you ever cleaned your oven?

Comment: @Stephie not really but these things must be coming from the top ceiling of the compartment or gas heating component.  i dont see why anything should be falling from there. As regards pics its really as I described, a few very small pieces of charcoal here and there not much at all so dont think pic will show much/may not be good quality to highlight the little dirt.

Comment: Wild guess: It is grease that baked onto the grill and comes off from time to time. Solution: Proper cleaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is in regard to an outdoor Weber grille.  According to the Weber grille people the black peelings are carbonized grease that accumulate when cooking and are not harmful. They might not be tasty though so I recommend a quick wipe to loosen the particles before cooking.  Again Weber suggests using aluminum foil to brush the top and I believe that is because aluminum is softer than steel and so won't scratch the surface.  Happy grilling!

Comment: Even though the OP was asking about an indoor oven, this answer may be correct.  I like it.